# What would I do with a .NET object hashcode?

Tags: c#, .net

An object in C# has four methods - {`Equals`, `GetType`, `ToString`, `GetHashCode`}.
What sort of useful thing could someone do with the hash-code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What sort of useful thing could someone do with the hashcode?

Quickly find *potentially* equal objects.

In particular, this method is usually used by types such as [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (for the keys) and [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

You should *not* assume that objects with equal hash codes are equal, however. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) for more information, and the [Wikipedia hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) page for a more general discussion on the uses of hash codes.

Comment: keys ? isnt the keys are considered different by the equals method ? ( IEquatable) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, but they're *first* compared by hash code - because that way you can cheaply get a *potential* match. Otherwise every fetch from a dictionary would require checking for equality against every key.

Comment: Why should the compiler bother doing potential matching if the equals can destroy its assumption ? ( I know that overriding equals demands overring getHashCode) - but thats another question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I never mentioned the *compiler* at all. But as for why it's worth *potentially* matching - if you've got a dictionary with a million keys, would you rather check for two potential matches which both have the same hash code, or all million keys?

Comment: yeah it has nothing to do with compiler. thansk for correcting

Comment: @JonSkeet So different Hash codes wont get the chance to be checked for equality ? ( because they aren't potential match ) ? Thanks for replying.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes - if two objects have different hash codes, they *must* be non-equal (to obey the contract) so there's no point in comparing them for equality. Read the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2):

> A hash code is a numeric value that is used to identify an object
>   during equality testing. It can also serve as an index for an object
>   in a collection.
>
> The GetHashCode method is suitable for use in hashing algorithms and
>   data structures such as a hash table.
>
> The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not
>   guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the
>   .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between
>   different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default
>   implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object
>   identifier for hashing purposes.
>
> The GetHashCode method can be overridden by a derived type. Value
>   types must override this method to provide a hash function that is
>   appropriate for that type and to provide a useful distribution in a
>   hash table. For uniqueness, the hash code must be based on the value
>   of an instance field or property instead of a static field or
>   property.
>
> Objects used as a key in a Hashtable object must also override the
>   GetHashCode method because those objects must generate their own hash
>   code. If an object used as a key does not provide a useful
>   implementation of GetHashCode, you can specify a hash code provider
>   when the Hashtable object is constructed. Prior to the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, the hash code provider was based on the
>   System.Collections.IHashCodeProvider interface. Starting with version
>   2.0, the hash code provider is based on the
>   System.Collections.IEqualityComparer interface.

[- Sourced from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that if two objects have a different hash code, they are different. If they have the same hash code, they could be different or equal.

To check if an object is present in a collection, you can first check against the hash codes, which is quick given you are comparing integers, and then do a more accurate test only on the objects with the same hash code.

This is used in the collection classes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

## GetHashCode

`GetHashCode` exists only for the benefit of these two types

->**HashTable**

->**GenericDictionary**

GetHashCode gives you varied keys for good `hashtable` performance.

## Equals

Equals provides a `null-safe` equality comparison when types are unknown at compile time.
its signature is

`public static bool Equals(object A,object B)`.

So you cant use operators like `==` or `!=` if the type is unknown at compile time.You have to use `Equals`

Its useful when writing generic types

For Example:

```
class Test<T>
{
    T value;
    public void SetV(T newValue)
   {
   if(object.Equals(newValue,value))
   //We have to use Object.Equals cant use == or !=since they cannot bind to unknown type at compile time
   }
}
```

## ToString

It returns default `texual representation` of a type instance.This method is overridden by all built in types

## GetType

`GetType` is evaluated at runtime.It helps us to know the type's `name`,`assemby`,`base type`..and others