# Are we guaranteed that hashcode caching through data race will work correctly?

Tags: .net, concurrency, volatile, memory-model

```
public class TestHashRace
{
    private int cachedHash = 0;
    private readonly object value;

    public object Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }

    public TestHashRace(object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (cachedHash == 0) {
            cachedHash = value.GetHashCode();
        }
        return cachedHash;
    }

    //Equals isn't part of the question, but since comments request it, here we go:
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((TestHashRace) obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(TestHashRace other)
    {
        return Equals(value, other.value);
    }
}
```

Here's simple test class.

Are we guaranteed that `GetHashCode` will always return the same value? 
And if we are, can someone point to some reference material which gives us this guarantee?

We aren't worried if it calculates hashcode for our value more than once, we just want to be sure that the returned value will always be the same.

Our class has to be immutable, while the `cachedHash` field is mutable. Field cannot be volatile for performance reasons (the whole idea of this question and optimization we are questioning here). Value is immutable. And it has to be thread-safe.

We can live with potential hashcode recalculation when it will be 0 for some specifc values. We do not want to use nullable types or add additional fields for memory reasons (less memory used if we store only 1 int), so it has to be one int field to handle hashcode problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You have no way of knowing when `value` will change - anything holding an external reference of it could potentially modify it, rendering your cached hash value stale.  Do you want the "same" hash code or do you want the "correct" hash?  The only way this can work is if the `value` object can notify the containing class if has been modified in a way that will alter its hash (or you need some way to guarantee that `value` will not be externally changed - store a clone or deep copy, etc).  Does this need to be threadsafe?  Too many questions here...

Comment: Overriding GetHashCode without overriding Equals will lead to errors. You need to show the equals implementation too

Comment: @J... edited question to meet your requirements

Comment: "Field cannot be volatile for performance reasons"  what are these performance reasons? Have you verified that this would be a bottleneck actually?

Comment: Your equals is wrong. If you get True for equals you must also get the same value with GetHashCode from both objects. Also your equals is currently infinitely recursive because you don't have a Equals overload that takes in a TestHashRace

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160370/569302

Comment: @BartoszKP I am not saying that we got a performance problem. I am asking if removing volatile in this code will work correctly in C#.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub Well, you're the one who said "performance reasons". I'm only asking what are these reasons.

Comment: Fyi, volatile has no performance impact in this case on x86. The instructions don't change. I don't see what JIT optimization would be inhibited by it (here). But it also has no correctness impact.

Comment: @usr sounds very interesting, can you elaborate more? Some links, references, proof? This kind of answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: Under the ECMA spec synchronization is required here for correctness. But no real world JIT would break this. I'd compare the machine code that the JIT generates with and without volatile (feel free to post it). Release mode, x64, make the debugger not prevent opimizations. I don't know why there would be a difference.

Answer (score 6):

> Are we guaranteed that GetHashCode will always return the same value?

No. The guarantee holds only for immutable `value` objects with properly implemented `GetHashCode` method. Mutable objects may change their hash code when their content has been mutated (which is the reason why mutable objects should not be used as hash keys).

This is true even if `TestHashRace` itself is immutable, because you can do this:

```
var evil = new StringBuilder("hello");
var thr = new TestHashRace(evil);
RunConcurrentCode(thr);
evil.Append(", world!");
```

If multiple threads in `RunConcurrentCode` start the call to `thr`'s `GetHashCode` at the same time, and then complete on different sides of `Append`, the number returned from `value.GetHashCode` may be different.

> [**Edit:**] Value is immutable

Then the only thing required for the guarantee to hold is that `value`'s `GetHashCode` is properly implemented, i.e. does not use random stuff etc.

**Note:** Since zero is a legitimate value for hash code, your code may repeatedly call `value`'s `GetHashCode` when the actual code is zero. One approach to fix this would be using nullable `cachedHash`:

```
int? cachedHash;
...
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return cachedHash ?? (cachedHash = value.GetHashCode());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added a few edits to the question. It's natural to say that we are guaranteed the same value, but where does this guarantee come from? Some proof, reference or something would be great.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub It comes from immutability of the object, and the assumption that `GetHashCode` behaves like a pure function, i.e. returns the same value for the same combination of input parameters. In this case input parameters are the state of the object. From Microsoft: ["The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: "In this case input parameters are the state of the object." - but the state of our object can be different in our case, hashcode changes state of the object. It tries to appear like a pure function, but it isn't pure. Hence the question.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub Your object is fine, it has no say in what's returned. It's `value` object that's in question.

Comment: It is absolutely fine to use mutable objects as keys as long as their GetHashCode is not overridden.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't because 0 is a valid result for `value.GetHashCode()`. Make cacheedHash a nullable int and check for null instead of 0.

Answer (score -1):

There is no guarantee, because you may go and implement a class with a `GetHashCode` method doing arbitrary stupid things. The compiler will not prevent you from that.

The other question is can you expect that `GetHashCode` always returns the same value. The answer to that question is yes, mostly. It is a design decision. However, for most classes, the ability to use instances as a key in a dictionary is important enough to implement `GetHashCode` in a way that the value never changes, for example by not overriding it, or only overriding it to save the reflection costs.

Notably, this includes `StringBuilder`, so that the race condition noted by dasblinkenlight does not really exist: Unlike `String`, `StringBuilder` will always return the same hash code.

So why mostly? The answer to this is a bit awkward. Technically, the class `string` is not immutable. There are some evil (i.e., unsafe) ways to modify the contents of a string without changing the reference, which in turn will lead to different hash codes for that same reference. You also will find a number of people implementing a value-like `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for classes that suffer from the same problem (and you do not have to use unsafe code to get in trouble).

Thus, there is no guarantee, but it is a fair assumption to make. Just document that assumption so users of your code do not run into trouble and you should be fine.

Comment: Why downvote? Please leave a comment if you think that something is not correct.